# Catch-all view break URL patterns in Django

Tags: python, django

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    url_patterns = [path("admin_profile", self.admin_view(self.profile_view))]
    return urls + url_patterns
```

The above method cause the catch-all view to break URL patterns which I route after the admin URLs and cause the following error/exception:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/admin_profile/ Raised
> by:   django.contrib.admin.sites.catch_all_view

But this only happen when

> final_catch_all_view = True

in

> django.contrib.admin.sites.catch_all_view

When setting

> final_catch_all_view = False

No error or exception is made,  everything went fine.

Now my question is how can make the function work when

> final_catch_all_view = True

And this is what docs say about catch_all view:

```
> The new admin catch-all view will break URL patterns routed after the
> admin URLs and matching the admin URL prefix. You can either adjust
> your URL ordering or, if necessary, set AdminSite.final_catch_all_view
> to False, disabling the catch-all view. See What’s new in Django 3.2
> for more details.
```

Class that urls are appended for:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.urls import path


class BookrAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    site_header = "Bookr Administration"
    logout_template = "admin/logout.html"

    def profile_view(self, request):
        request.current_app = self.name
        context = self.each_context(request)
        return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/admin_profile.html", context)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        url_patterns = [path("admin_profile", self.admin_view(self.profile_view))]
        return url_patterns + urls
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from reviews import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include(('django.contrib.auth.urls', 'auth'), namespace='accounts')),
    path('accounts/profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('reviews.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please include your urls.py file, the class that you're appending the URL for, and the code that registers the ModelAdmin class.

Comment: Included; not sure if admin.py code may help here

Comment: I wonder if there's an issue with using `AdminSite.get_urls`. Try applying it on the profile's ModelAdmin subclass https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls rather than AdminSite. If that works, you can work backwards to determine what went wrong with your original approach.

Answer (score 4):

The docs seem to indicate that you need to specify your custom URLs before the django admin URLs. In your `get_urls` override function, you're appending rather than prepending the custom url. Try the following:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    url_patterns = [path("admin_profile", self.admin_view(self.profile_view))]
    return url_patterns + urls
```