# django-import-export-celery summary page not found

Tags: django, django-import-export, django-import-export-celery

I have created a new task in `django-import-export-celery` and it has successfully imported the tasks.

[image]

But I cannot view the summary of the changes.

[image]

I already added this in my `urlpatterns`:

[image]

The files are present on my directory, but they cannot show the view. I'm following this [repo](https://github.com/auto-mat/django-import-export-celery) as my reference.

**EDIT**: The line `url(r'^', admin.site.urls),` messes up with the URL. When I remove it, I can see the template, but all other app pages do not show. When I let it stay, I can see all other pages but the template throws an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch-all view break URL patterns in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368142/catch-all-view-break-url-patterns-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put static first like so:

```
urlpatterns = static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
) + [
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
]
```